# Как решить ошибку при тестировании angular

Tags: angularjs, юнит-тесты

Тестирую метод провайдер:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('ngTokenAuth', ['ngCookies'])
.provider('$auth', function () {

  $get: function ($http, $q, $log, $cookieStore, $rootScope, $interpolate, $timeout) {
    return {
      user: {},
      userAuth: false,
      userFirstUpdate: false,


      login: function (params) {
        var _this = this;
        var dfd = $q.defer();
        $http.post(configs.apiUrl + configs.loginPath, params)
          .success(function (resp) {
            _this.setAuthorized(resp);
            _this.setAuthorizedHeader(resp);
            return dfd.resolve(resp);
          })
          .error(function () {
            return dfd.reject();
          });
        return dfd.promise;
      }   
    }
  }
};
```

Тесты:

```
    describe('Тестируем провайдер аутентификации $auth', function () {

  //Поскольку я использую ui-router, то приходится делать кастомный загрузчик
  beforeEach(module('webConsole', function($provide, $translateProvider){
    $provide.factory('customLoader', function ($q) {
      return function () {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        deferred.resolve({});
        return deferred.promise;
      };
    });

    $translateProvider.useLoader('customLoader');

  }));

  beforeEach(module('ngTokenAuth'));

  var $auth;
  var $httpBackend;
  var $rootScope;
  var dfd;


  beforeEach(inject(function (_$auth_, _$httpBackend_, _$cookieStore_, _$rootScope_, $q) {
    $auth = _$auth_;
    $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
    $cookieStore = _$cookieStore_;
    $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
    dfd = $q.defer();
    spyOn($rootScope, '$broadcast');
  }));

    describe("Тестируем метод login", function () {

      describe("Тестируем положительный ответ от сервера", function () {

        var data = {
          "token": "cm9vdApwb3J0....mRFaUUDto2Ro9bI0oqSrToC0w1OdUeeMDHkRedg="
        };

        beforeEach(function () {


          console.log(data)
          dfd.resolve(data);

          spyOn($auth, 'login').and.returnValue(dfd.promise);
        });

        afterEach(function() {
          $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
          $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
        });

        it("spec name", function () {

          var result;

          $auth.login()
            .then(function(resp){
              console.log(resp)
              result = resp;
            });

          $httpBackend.flush();
          expect(result).toEqual(data)
        });


      });

    });
});
```

В итоге я получаю ошибку:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'defaultPrevented' of undefined
...
Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $digest already in progress
    http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.8/$rootScope/inprog?p0=%24digest
...
```

Тест работает если не использовать кастомный загрузчик вначале, но тогда появлется баг описанный здесь ([Unit Testing with angular-translate](http://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/guide/22_unit-testing-with-angular-translate)).